# Fake CRT effect on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to be able to make my canvas look as though it's on a curved and rounded CRT screen, similar to these two images:

[image: Image one]
[image: Image two]

How would I do this to an HTML5 canvas? I would be happy to do it within the canvas drawing itself, or with a CSS style applied to the canvas.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2012/08/17/webgl-fake-crt-html5.html

Comment: @RudieVisser I think it is - could you submit it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick search gave me this website: [WebGL Fake CRT Effect for HTML5 Games](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2012/08/17/webgl-fake-crt-html5.html),
it uses the [glfx.js](http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/) library.

> It is a library meant to apply realtime WebGL effects to an image, but the `canvas` tag can actually be addressed as an image source...

The demo uses [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPN59.png) image to overwrite onto the `canvas`.

And the code to actually create the effect:

```
// Make sure you've included the glfx.js script in your code!

// Here I load a PNG with scanlines that I overwrite onto the 2D game's canvas.
// This file happens to be customized for the demo game, so to make this a
// general solution we'll need a generic scanline image or we'll generate them
// procedurally.
// Start loading the image right away, not after the onload event.
var lines = new Image();
lines.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPN59.png';

window.addEventListener('load', fakeCRT, false);

function fakeCRT() {
    var glcanvas, source, srcctx, texture, w, h, hw, hh, w75;

    // Try to create a WebGL canvas (will fail if WebGL isn't supported)
    try {
       glcanvas = fx.canvas();
    } catch (e) {return;}

    // Assumes the first canvas tag in the document is the 2D game, but
    // obviously we could supply a specific canvas element here.
    source = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    srcctx = source.getContext('2d');

    // This tells glfx what to use as a source image
    texture = glcanvas.texture(source);

    // Just setting up some details to tweak the bulgePinch effect
    w = source.width;
    h = source.height;
    hw = w / 2;
    hh = h / 2;
    w75 = w * 0.75;

    // Hide the source 2D canvas and put the WebGL Canvas in its place
    source.parentNode.insertBefore(glcanvas, source);
    source.style.display = 'none';
    glcanvas.className = source.className;
    glcanvas.id = source.id;
    source.id = 'old_' + source.id;

    // It is pretty silly to setup a separate animation timer loop here, but
    // this lets us avoid monkeying with the source game's code.
    // It would make way more sense to do the following directly in the source
    // game's draw function in terms of performance.
    setInterval(function () {
        // Give the source scanlines
        srcctx.drawImage(lines, 0, 0, w, h);

        // Load the latest source frame
        texture.loadContentsOf(source);

        // Apply WebGL magic
        glcanvas.draw(texture)
            .bulgePinch(hw, hh, w75, 0.12)
            .vignette(0.25, 0.74)
            .update();
    }, Math.floor(1000 / 40));
}
```

> Usually works, although I should warn you that Safari 6 managed to freeze my entire system for a minute at least a couple times... but not every time. You might be happier in Chrome.

Comment: Great catch! Would be nice if you could add some related code directly in your answer.

Comment: @morgul added an example.